# unable to get NDMS plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, vegan

I was trying to get a NDMS plot out of my dataframe which is an abundance table.
However i ended up with error. Im new to R and im not sure where im going wrong

dataframe:

```
"Level_1"   "Day"   "Yield" "Acidobacteria" "candidate division NC10"   "candidate division WOR-3"  "Candidatus Aminicenantes"  "Candidatus Eisenbacteria"  "Candidatus Rokubacteria"   "Calditrichaeota"   "Elusimicrobia" "Bacteroidetes" "Ignavibacteriae"   "candidate division Zixibacteria"   "Candidatus Latescibacteria"    "Gemmatimonadetes"  "Nitrospirae"   "Proteobacteria"    "Candidatus Abyssubacteria" "Candidatus Omnitrophica"   "Lentisphaerae" "Planctomycetes"    "Verrucomicrobia"   "Spirochaetes"  "Actinobacteria"    "Armatimonadetes"   "Chloroflexi"   "Cyanobacteria" "Deinococcus-Thermus"   "Firmicutes"
"R11P4_BS_diamond"  0   "Low"   22225.703   574.2619    0   140.88957   2322.9353   0   1029.0415   19.166956   3195.5298   256.63806   0.995686    0   1352.266    3617.2026   29759.188   0   28.37705    102.057816  4175.409    3554.35 1059.6588   5686.363    666.98517   35559.43    4108.5737   6.845341    2762.282
"R13P1_BS_diamond"  60  "High"  34864.668   296.10495   0   96.91555    970.3203    0   1011.2066   21.433247   3125.6428   382.53687   0.5824252   0   740.0294    8325.418    26701.049   0   43.33243    95.63422    2905.2532   5159.7046   1287.509    5290.517    720.45996   36515.844   3476.9617   7.105587    3380.0461
"R13P3_BS_diamond"  60  "High"  30511.857   201.64407   1252.1503   160.40663   1576.6329   0   0   20.618717   3181.9224   527.6994    0.17473489  0   618.5615    5305.126    27084.434   0   72.86445    81.251724   3752.0823   4092.466    2143.2983   6419.4106   869.3061    35032.426   3004.916    5.5915165   2518.454
"R13P6_BS_diamond"  60  "Low"   23491.105   201.67783   0   115.17029   2832.317    0   0   20.043161   2692.534    1185.2467   0   0   2077.0115   1735.1355   38256.37    0   1011.81616  99.385  4316.4453   4472.325    917.51984   9140.408    1159.6995   21273.375   3704.8694   7.061839    2208.4863
"R14P1_BS_diamond"  90  "High"  21952.639   196.00256   0   37.935978   1538.1635   0   0   0   3867.7136   1045.1714   0   0   924.8651    1710.6316   32768.605   0   0   0   3437.2456   2696.6157   1705.3628   14147.135   1296.3215   33106.695   3081.4202   11.24029    2023.2522
"R14P3_BS_diamond"  90  "High"  23845.86    189.5785    0   121.52756   1219.4237   0   0   19.843521   3474.5222   285.2086    0.3363309   0   1093.2996   4346.6284   32942.938   0   37.66906    97.19962    3969.1528   4942.8306   761.90155   9911.335    933.76666   34448.355   3229.0007   7.6235  2885.943
```

code:

```
library(vegan)
pc = read.csv("/media/combio7/8TB_Backup/sumitra_130122/all_season_megan_metadata/NDMS/transposed-bs-allseason-230922-taxonomy-phylum.csv", header= TRUE,sep ='\t')

#make community matrix - extract columns with abundance information
com = pc[,4:ncol(pc)]

#turn abundance data frame into a matrix
m_com = as.matrix(com)

set.seed(123)
nmds = metaMDS(m_com, distance = "bray")
nmds
plot(nmds)

#extract NMDS scores (x and y coordinates)
data.scores = as.data.frame(scores(nmds)$sites)


data.scores$Sample = pc$Sample
data.scores$Time = pc$Day
data.scores$Type = pc$Yield

head(data.scores)

library(ggplot2)

xx = ggplot(data.scores, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2)) + 
    geom_point(size = 4, aes( shape = Type, colour = Time))+ 
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold"), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 12), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face ="bold", colour ="black"), 
    legend.position = "right", axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, colour = "black"), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "bold"), 
    panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.2),
    legend.key=element_blank()) + 
    labs(x = "NMDS1", colour = "Type", y = "NMDS2", shape = "Time")  + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#E69F00"))
```

error:
'Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale'

changed to:

```
xx = ggplot(data.scores, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2)) + 
    geom_point(size = 4, aes( shape = as.factor(Type), colour = as.factor(Time)))+ 
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold"), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 12), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face ="bold", colour ="black"), 
    legend.position = "right", axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, colour = "black"), 
    legend.title = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "bold"), 
    panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.2),
    legend.key=element_blank()) + 
    labs(x = "NMDS1", colour = as.factor("Time"), y = "NMDS2", shape = as.factor("Type"))  + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#E69F00"))
```

error:
Error in f():! Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 2 provided.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The issue with your first code is of course that your `Time` or `Day` column is a numeric. The issue with your second code is, that as the error says you provided only two colors to scale_colour_manual while `Time` or `Day` has four different values. To fix that add two more colors.

Comment: hi @stefan, thank you so much, i added 2 more colors and now its working